# Pyinstaller --onefile executable only works if QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH is set

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, executable, pyinstaller

ERROR: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".

ISSUE: I can solve this by specifying the QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable to C:\Users\esandberg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14h6f8c307_12\Library\plugins\platforms
But then it will only run on my own computer. I don't know how to make it run on computers I send the one-file executable to.

DESIRED SOLUTION: A way to have my executable automatically know where the Qt platform plugins are when bundled and deployed to other computers.

I'm trying to use PyInstaller to generate a single file executable for a program I wrote. My program has the following imports:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import imageio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy.fft as fft
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as FD
import time
from scipy import signal
```

Here is my PyInstaller command:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --hidden-import=tkinter --hidden-import=scipy --hidden-import=matplotlib --hidden-import=fixtk --hidden-import=scipy.integrate MY_FILE_NAME.py
```

Please note: The executable works fine on all computers UNTIL a user tries to make a plot using a tkinter button. That's when it crashes and the ERROR is shown.

I have tried solutions from every similar question and none have worked, so please help tackle this unique case!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Erik

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking your libs dynamically, you need to ship some libraries with the executable. In your install Qt folder, you'll find the folder plugins/platforms.

The easiest (and nastiest) way to achieve what you want to do is to put those libs in the same folder as the executable.

A better way would be to use [QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath) to ensure the application will find its libs even without the env variable.

If you want to link your libs statically, you need to modify your `.pro` file to specify what plugins to use. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins).

Also, [more doc about deployement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#creating-the-application-package).

Comment: It worked the nasty way (I can make a folder \platforms\ in the same folder as my executable and put qwindows.dll inside \platforms\) but then it's no longer a single file executable. How can I make the  QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(...) work in Python?

Comment: I was wondering the exat same thing. I don't know either PyInstaller nor tkinter but I believe tkinter should be the one providing the libraries. Maybe there's some clues in the tkinter doc ?

Comment: I've found it ! You should take a look to [PyInstaller's spec files](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

This particular error was caused by my using of Python 3.6.
I switched to Python 3.4, ran pyinstaller on the exact same script, and there is no longer an issue with the qwindows dll! A new problem has arisen though - trying to import scipy.signal. Hope this helps anyone who looks!